# How to bulk renaming ebooks

Tags: metadata

Is there a simple way for renaming a lot of ebooks, getting the relevant information from their metadata? Of course I can open the ebook, copy the data and renaming one file at a time, but since the information is always in the same place it should not be difficult to have a program or an app where I can specify a format (like for example "%a-%t-%i") and ending up with titles like "Terry Pratchett-Going Postal-9780060502935.epub"

Answer (score 1):

since nobody answered, I did a search and found [ebook-tools](https://github.com/na--/ebook-tools). Probably `organize-ebooks.sh` would have been the best choice, but I tried `rename-calibre-library.sh` and after a long sed script I ended up with the result I needed.